MySQL treats "identical" strings as different
I have a table with email column.  The emails are supposed to be unique.
Using like
SELECT email FROM `table`
WHERE `email` LIKE 'name@domain.com'

Result: one row is displayed
using like % .. %
SELECT email `table`
WHERE `email` LIKE '%name@domain.com%'

Result: two rows are displayed  (apparently identical emails)
Using DISTINCT in the queries yields the same results as bove
Charset: utf8
Collation: latin1_swedish_ci
There are no white spaces or hidden non-alphanumeric characters in the email
How can this be resolved?

Have retrieved emails and saved them in a text file. Reading file using notepadd ++ displays identical emails again. Printing them again displays no difference. how can the the  hexadecimal string be compared, please?

Use SELECT HEX(email) .. and compare.

The issue was caused by some emails having a "line feed" and a "carriage return" at the end.  Mysql treated what appeared to be identical emails as different.
To correct this, I used the following command from within PhpMyAdmin
UPDATE `table` SET `column` = REPLACE(`column`, '\r\n','') where column LIKE '%\r\n';

I thank posters of the comments who helped me solve it.

Note, you are allowed to tick your answer after 24 hours.
